# Android clean device cache

Tags: android

Please let me know how to clean device cache programmaticlly?

Thanks

Comment: CPU memory cache? Disk cache? /cache directory on the disk?

Comment: I like to know all kind of the cache. PLease let me know the path and process to clean.

Answer (score 1):

If you put files in `getCacheDir()` for your application, you can delete those whenever you want, using normal file I/O.

You have no rights to modify, let alone clear, any caches for any other applications or the operating system.

Comment: i agree with the answer but there are so manny apps are there in the market which provide the feature to clean complete cache. If you can guide me how they do....will enough hint to solve the issue.

Comment: @Android_IT: "but there are so manny apps are there in the market which provide the feature to clean complete cache" -- any that do are exploiting a security loophole somewhere. If you can name any applications that have this feature, I will work to ensure that the loophole is found and closed, so malware like this can do less harm in the future.

Comment: @ CommonsWare: http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/best%20cache%20cleaner